# Error trying to create a pod in namespace with kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

I'm new to Kubernetes and I'm trying to create a pod inside a namespace.

I have the following namesapce.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
   name: swirlai
```

The following configMap.yaml is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
   name: config
   namespace: swirlai
data:
   enviroment: dev # Key - Value
   db-host: localhost # Key - Value
   airflow.cfg:
    dags_folder = ../CodeExample/airflow/dags
    base_log_folder = ../CodeExample/airflow/logs
```

The secret.yaml is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret
  namespace: swirlai
data:
  secret-data: c3VwZXItc2VjcmV0
```

And the pod.yaml is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: swirlai-pod
  namespace: swirlai
spec:
  containers:
  - name: swirlai-container
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    env:
    - name: DIRECT
      value: Some String
    - name: ENVIRONMENT
      valueFrom:
         configMapKeyRef:
           name: config
           key: environment
    - name: SECRET_DATA
      valueFrom:
         secretKeyRef:
           name: secret
           key: secret-data
```

After running the "kubectl apply -f pod.yaml" command I can see that I have an error with the command  "describe pod -n swirlai"

The error is:

Error: couldn't find key environment in ConfigMap swirlai/config

Answer (score 1):

in the `pod.yaml` file,under the configMapKeyRef.key you should put `environment` instead of `dev`.

EDIT: better explanation :

In the file `pod.yaml`, you put the the value of the ConfigMap (`dev`) instead of the key (`environment`).
The value of of the `key` should be the key in the ConfigMap, so in your example the key should be environment, like so:

```yaml
configMapKeyRef:
  name: config
  key: environment
```

Comment: I made a mistake while writing the question, I ran the pod.yaml originally with environment. (I fixed the question now)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).